# Why is the k-means clustering scatter plot showing different results?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn, k-means

I have two datasets(data.csv, label.csv).The "label.csv" dataset contains the gene names of the samples on "data.csv" dataset. I want to run k-means clustering algorithm in those datasets and make a scatter plot. But I am having difficulties in it. Below I have given the code that I performed for getting the clustering done.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

X = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
Y = pd.read_csv("labels.csv")

#reduce the dimension of X
import time
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

X = X.dropna()
# drop the first column which only contains strings
X = X.drop(X.columns[X.columns.str.contains('unnamed', case=False)], axis=1)

# label encode the multiple class string into integer values
Y = Y.drop(Y.columns[0], axis=1)
le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit(Y)
class_names = list(le.classes_)

Y = Y.apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
Y_data = Y.values.flatten()

# use TSNE to visualize the high dimension data in 2D
t0 = time.time()
tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, verbose=1, perplexity=40, n_iter=300, random_state=100)
tsne_results = tsne.fit_transform(X)
t1 = time.time()
print("TSNE took at %.2f seconds" % (t1 - t0))

# visualize TSNE
x_axis = tsne_results[:,0]
y_axis = tsne_results[:,1]

plt.scatter(x_axis, y_axis, c=Y_data, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap("jet", 100))

plt.colorbar(ticks=range(10))
plt.clim(-0.5, 9.5)
plt.title("TSNE Visualization")
plt.show()
```

The code above gives a scatter plot(given below) of the 5 different classes in my datasets. the classes are colored differently from 0 to 4 (5 classes).

[image]

But when I apply K-means clustering code(given below) it shows 5 clusters but the classes colors are not from 0 0 to 4 instead it ranges from 0 to 9. The scatter plot image is given below the k means cluster code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

model=KMeans(n_clusters=5)
model.fit(tsne_results)
label=model.predict(tsne_results)

#centroid calculation
xs =tsne_results[:,0]
ys =tsne_results[:,1]
plt.scatter(xs,ys,c=Y_data,alpha=0.5)

centroids = model.cluster_centers_
centroids_x = centroids[:,0]
centroids_y = centroids[:,1]

plt.scatter(centroids_x, centroids_y, marker='D', s=50)
plt.colorbar(ticks=range(10))
plt.clim(-0.5, 9.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now, in which part of the code do I need to bring change in order to get a scatter plot like the first one showing the colored classes from 0 to 4 for 5 clusters.

Comment: What if you change `plt.clim(-0.5, 9.5)` to e.g. `plt.clim(-0.5, 5.5)`?

Comment: you set colorbar tick range up to 9.5 in you code (second block)...that's why. set to 4.5

Answer (score -1):

I don't see what the problem here is. You have 5 different clusters colored differently, and i think it's just the coloring that ranges from 0-9, with the centroids being their own color. So unless you specifically need them to range 0-4 for some reason, i would use this plot. You can see the clusters, and the centroids, which is all you really need.

The code to look at though would be

```
plt.colorbar(ticks=range(10))
plt.clim(-0.5, 9.5)
```